# nginx locations with similar prefixes

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to do configure nginx to serve different version of an Angular SPA, usually prefixed with "dev" or "prod" but having a location that is "dev" and "prod", but i don't want nginx to expose directories that are not configured (inside nginx.conf).

For example,

```
http://myserver/dev  
http://myserver/dev-SomeFeatureBranch
```

If I use exact matching (= modifier), I can't reach anything below /dev or below /dev-SomeFeatureBranch, so that's not an option.

If I don't specify a modifier, I get prefix matching which kinda works but exposes other branches that I have not configured in my nginx.conf

For example, if i have a directory named "dev-SomePrivateBranch" in the same directory as my other Dev branches and I use the following configs:

```
    location / {
        root   ../www;
    }
    location /dev {
        alias ../dev;
    }

    location /dev-SomeFeatureBranch {
        alias ../dev-SomeFeatureBranch;
    }
```

I can effectively reach http://myserver/dev-SomePrivateBranch , since it matches "/dev" but i don't want to reach locations that i have not explicitly configured.

Add to that issues with trailing slashes, I'd like http://myserver/dev/ to work as well as http://myserver/dev

I'm sure this is super simple once you are used to nginx's ways, but i can't seem to get that working for the life of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a trailing `/` if you want your locations to refer to a single directory name rather than a random set of directory names that happen to begin with the same characters.

For example:

```
location / {
    root  ../www;
}
location /dev/ {
    alias ../dev/;
}
location /dev-SomeFeatureBranch/ {
    alias ../dev-SomeFeatureBranch/;
}
```

Note that the `location` and `alias` directives should both end with `/`.

---

The `alias` is probably unnecessary, as `root ..;` should work if the location name and directory name are the same.

For example:

```
location / {
    root  ../www;
}
location /dev/ {
    root  ..;
}
location /dev-SomeFeatureBranch/ {
    root  ..;
}
```

I do not like relative paths for `root` and `alias`, but it should still work if that's what you prefer.

---

The efficient solution to manage `/dev` and `/dev/` is to redirect from one to the other. Nginx does this automatically if the directory exists. But in your case, it's not obvious as the initial URI is processed in the `location /` block. You can solve the problem with an explicit redirect.

For example:

```
location / {
    root  ../www;
}
location = /dev { return 301 /dev/; }
location /dev/ {
    root  ..;
}
location = /dev-SomeFeatureBranch { return 301 /dev-SomeFeatureBranch/; }
location /dev-SomeFeatureBranch/ {
    root  ..;
}
```

---

Finally, if the root is the same for all the `location` blocks, you may as well use a regular expression, in which case the entire solution can be wrapped up into one expression.

For example:

```
location / {
    root  ../www;
}
location ~ ^/dev(|-SomeFeatureBranch)($|/) {
    root  ..;
}
```

Note that the evaluation order of regular expression `location` blocks is significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thanks! That works exactly as expected and also a big thanks for the extra explanations, i get it now!